# Getting userInfo state as null from React.Context in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to set the data in an object which I have created for global state management.

State:

```
  const [isloggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(undefined);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    data: "",
    location: "",
  });
```

store:

```
  const store = useMemo(
    () => ({
      authToken: [token, setToken],
      logInfo: [isloggedIn, setIsLoggedIn],
      userData: [userInfo, setUserInfo],
    }),
    [token, isloggedIn, userInfo],
  );
```

I have provide store to my `Auth` navigation and `main` navigation but when I am trying to set `data` like this `userInfo.data` I am getting null. But when I do the same thing  in navigation then I am able to do it. And, if I try to do `setUserInfo({data: user.data })` then I am still getting null in navigation.

Navigation:

```
  if (token) {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={store}>
        <MainNavigationStack />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={store}>
      <AuthNavigationStack />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

I don't know why I am getting `userInfo` as `null` in console.log in `navigation` and in `Auth` screens? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set your `userInfo` like

```js
setUserInfo(userInfo => ({
    ...userInfo,
    ...updatedValue
  }));
})
```